# Child routing module not loading the content in the same page

Tags: angular, components, router, router-outlet

I'm working on small application indicating with angular 2. [ Authentication + 2 screens ], i have a problem managing my routing parameters.

I made to routing file, the **app.routing.ts** principal, and the a child routing file **admin.routing.ts**, whenever i authenticate successfully, a redirection is made to **home** path, in this page i have to components, managed by the child router, whenever i click on link i expect content loading in the same screen, but the router reloads the entire page.

**app.routing.ts**

```
      const  appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component : HomeComponent,
        canActivate : [AuthGard]
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component : LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'not-found',
        component: NotFoundComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo : 'not-found',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
  ];

  export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**adminRouting.ts (child)**

```
  const  appRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'add-merchant-admin',
    component : AddMerchantAdminComponent,
    canActivate : [AuthGard]
  },
  {
    path: 'list-merchant-admin',
    component : ListMerchantAdminComponent,
    canActivate : [AuthGard]
  }
];
```

**home.component.html**

```
<app-template-component></app-template-component>
<app-sidebar-nav></app-sidebar-nav>
```

**template.component.html**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-panel">

    <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet> ** Content expected to be loaded here  **
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="copyright pull-right">
          &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> S2M 2017
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

     </div>
</div>
```

**Figure**

[image]

instead of loading the content in the indicated place, it loads another page.

Answer (score 0):

Child routes are supposed to be defined like this

```
const  appRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component : HomeComponent,
        canActivate : [AuthGard],
        children:[
        {
             path:'', 
             component:ChildComponent,
             children: appRoutesChild
         }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component : LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'not-found',
        component: NotFoundComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo : 'not-found',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
  ];
```